# Will reseting my device to factory setting unroot and remove superuser?

Tags: unrooting

As the title says, if I reset my rooted nexus 4 to factory settings will it be unrooted relocked and superuser uninstalled?

Answer (score 1):

No, root won't be removed by factory reset. If you want to remove it, then you should flash stock ROM; or delete the su binary from the `system/bin` and `system/xbin` and then delete the Superuser app from the `system/app`.

Comment: So just deleting those two folders and SuperSU will completly remove root?

Comment: Sort of. But to be safe use a application like [OTA Root Keeper](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.projectvoodoo.otarootkeeper&hl=en). In this application there is an option to temp un-root (keeps a backup of su binary). But If you’d like to make it more permanent, click the “delete su backup” button. You can then click “Restore Root” whenever you want to bring the root back.

Comment: You can't "restore root" without a "su backup".